Schwartz's theorem without English language reference
I'm reading the paper "Spectral Synthesis And The Pompeiu Problem" by Leon Brown, Bertram M. Schreiber and B. Alan Taylor,
Annales de l’Institut Fourier 23, No. 3, 125-154 (1973), MR352492, Zbl 0265.46044. They gave some theorems with a reference in French which I could not understand. They may be very famous theorems but I'm fresh to complex analysis. I wish you could give me some references in English so that I can learn them.
In the theorems below

$\mathscr{E}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ denotes the space of all infinitely differentiable functions on $\Bbb{R}^n$ with its usual topology, and
$\mathscr{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ its dual space, the space of distributions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The first theorem is denoted as 'fundamental theorem of mean-periodic functions'. I tried to search for it but got no clue. It was given with a reference to the paper "Théorie générale des fonctions moyenne-périodiques" by L. Schwartz, Annals of Mathematics, 2nd Series, 48, 857-929 (1947), MR23948, Zbl 0030.15004. It is written in French so I cannot read it.
Theorem 2.2: Let $I$ be an ideal in $\hat{\mathscr{E}}'(\Bbb{R})$ whose functions have no common zeros in $\mathbb{C}$. Then there exists a sequence of functions in $I$ converging to the constant function 1.
Furthermore, the authors claimed that the analogue of this theorem was not known for $n > 1$. As it's 50 years ago, do we have the analogue of the theorem for higher dimensions?
Another theorem was given with no reference:
Theorem 2.3: Let $V$ be a closed, translation-invariant subspace of $C(\Bbb{R}^n)$, and let $V_1 = V \cap \mathscr{E}(\Bbb{R}^n)$. Then $V_1$ is dense in $V$ in
the topology of $C(\Bbb{R}^n)$.
The authors claimed it is easy to prove by the standard smoothing procedure. I tried to prove it but failed. If we consider the convolution of $g\in V$ with a mollifier $\varphi$, it may still be translation-invariant subspace but why does it still belong to $V$ ? Do I need to use some other techniques to deal with it? I sincerely with to have some help from you.

Edit: For Theorem 2.3., @JochenWengenroth has given a brief proof in this and this comment below. I notice it here in case you may miss the comment ^_^.

Concerning Theorem 2.3: For a smooth approximation of unity $\psi_k$ (i.e., test functions with integral $1$ and supports tending to $0$) you have $f\ast \psi_k\to f$ in $C(\mathbb R^n)$. Moreover, $f\ast\psi_k(x)=\int f(x-y)\psi_k(y) dy$ is a limit of Riemannian sums whose terms are multiples of $x\mapsto f(x-y_\ell)\psi_k(y_\ell)$ which belong to $V$ by translation invariance.

Concerning the other theorem: Are you sure that $\mathcal S$ denotes the space of all smooth functions, the standard notation of Schwartz would be $\mathcal E$ whereas $\mathcal S$ usually denotes the space of rapidly decreasing smooth functions. Anyway, the dual is a space of distributions which are not necessarily functions. I thus do not understand what you mean by whose functions have no common zeros in $C$ (what is $C$?, b.t.w.)

@JochenWengenroth Thanks for pointing out that! You are right about the notation. I should have used $\mathcal{E}$ but not $\mathcal{S}$. I made that fault because I was thinking of smooth functions and I have changed the notations. About the $C$ notation, I understant it as $\mathbb{C}$ but the original text did not provide any notations so I did not dare to use that notation.

@JochenWengenroth As in the original text we have that $\mathcal{E}'$ has compact support, we may claim its Fourier transform is an entire function by Paley-Wiener_Schwartz theorem on $\mathbb{C}$ and that's the way we define common zeros here. This is my understanding.

@JochenWengenroth Thanks for your explaination of Thm. 2.3. That is a great help for me.

@JochenWengenroth I'm so sorry coz I missed the Fourier transformation notation. I've added it. Sorry for making confusion.
